# Registro y login en Javascript

Tags: javascript, login, registro

estaba intentando hacer un login y registro con javascript, cuando te registres quede el mail guardado en el localstorage o en el sesionstorage y con eso puedas logearte, la parte del registro ya la hice pero no se como validar el mail en el login, intento iterar el array donde guardo los mail y no puedo.Se que lo ideal no es hacer esto con javascript pero es para una tarea/proyecto, desde ya muchas gracias.

dejo el link del github https://github.com/Igna-vera/proyecto-carro2/tree/main/ProyectoCarro

```
    function formulario(){
   
    
    home.innerHTML="";
    $(`.home`).append(`
    <div class="container">
    <form id="formulario">
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control mailFormulario" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
      
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Contraseña</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control contraseñaFormulario" id="exampleInputPassword1">
    </div>
    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary botonIngreso">Ingresa</button>
  </form></div>`)

  function limpiarFormulario() {
    document.querySelector("#formulario").reset();
  }


//validar formulario



let nombreRegistro=[]
  console.log(nombreRegistro)
for(email of nombreRegistro){
    console.log("a")
}
  

//   console.log(nombreRegistro);

$(`.botonIngreso`).click(()=>{
    let mailFormulario=""
    let contraseñaFormulario=""
    mailFormulario=document.querySelector(`.mailFormulario`).value
    contraseñaFormulario=document.querySelector(`.contraseñaFormulario`).value
   

    registro()
  

    if(mailFormulario===""||mailFormulario===null){
        swal("Por favor, complete todos los datos correspondientes");

    // }if(mailFormulario===asd){
    //     console.log("usuario registrado")
    }
    
    
    if(contraseñaFormulario===""||contraseñaFormulario===""){
        swal("Por favor, complete todos los datos correspondientes");


    

    }else{
        swal("Bienvenido");
        limpiarFormulario()
        

    }
   
    
    

    
})


function registro(){
    $(`.home`).append(`<form>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control emailLocal" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
      <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3 form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary botonLocal">Submit</button>
  </form>`)
  
  //storage registro
  function añadirUsuario(pemail){
    let newUsuario={
        email:pemail,
    }
    nombreRegistro.push(newUsuario)
   jsonStorageUsuario(nombreRegistro)

}


$(`.botonLocal`).click(()=>{
    console.log("asd")
    let guardarMail=document.querySelector(`.emailLocal`).value
    
    añadirUsuario(guardarMail)
})

function getStorageUsuario(){
        let storageUsuario=localStorage.getItem("localRegistro")
    if(storageUsuario==null){
        nombreRegistro=[]
    }else{
        
        nombreRegistro=JSON.parse(storageUsuario)
    }
    return nombreRegistro
    
}


function jsonStorageUsuario(plista){
    localStorage.setItem("localRegistro",JSON.stringify(plista))

}
```

Comment: muchísima mala practica, tu código es ilegible

Comment: Mira, hizo el clone de tu repositorio en mi maquina local, y lo que pudo comprender testando tu app és que ni mismo estás guardando los datos en localStorage. Hay una o dos funcciones y variables que declarastes, pero no las usa ni siquiera una sola vez, talves una de ellas sea lo que falta. Por ejemplo, la funccion `getStorageUsuario()` está declarada, pero nunca usada, y ella me parece importante para el funccionamiento correcto de tu app. Además te recomiendo una refactoración del código, siento decirle que está un tanto mal escrito. Aconsejo mirar todo el código y entenderlo completamente

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.